# Objective-C: Add JSON response to SQLite DB

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5, sqlite, fmdb

I am getting a JSON response and would like to add it to an SQLite db. The results come back as an array and in each array there will be about 30 keys with values. What would be the most efficient approach to adding all those to my table? The keys coming from the JSON would be the columns in the sqlite db.

Would it be best to do a for loop on each array item then another for loop in side to get the values and add it to a string  then add them to the database that way? Or is there a better approach using FMDB to add a JSON response directly to the database if the json keys match the database table columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a loop and getting the json keys and using those as the columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe your JSON response will not change and your data model will not change (or rarely change), then I'd just loop through the arrays and write the slightly long...

```
[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO response (key1,key2,..key30) VALUES (?,?,?...etc);", json_reponse.value1,json_response.value2,...,json_response.value30, nil];
```

However, if this model would change, be extended, etc... then I'd probably just use Core Data.

The biggest factor though is what are you doing with the data after it is stored?  Creating objects, display a report, converting the objects back to JSON (then just store the raw JSON in a text field)?